# How to add day and time_stamp to the kafka stream output

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently aggregating Kafka streams and sending the count to a topic.I also need to add day and timestamp of the count.What is the best way to do this?

These are the configs i used:

```
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 60 * 1000);
```

code:

```
final KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregated = feeds
 .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getUserId().toString(), value))
.groupByKey()
.count(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1),STATE_STORE);

// We want to compute the total count of users, so we must re-key all records to the same key. 
aggregated.selectKey((k, v) -> "user_count as of  ")
            .transform(() -> new Transformer<String, Long, KeyValue<String, Long>>() {
                private ProcessorContext context;

                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                    this.context = context;
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, Long> transform(String key, Long value) {
                    long timestamp = context.timestamp();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss");
                    key = key + sdf.format(timestamp);
                    // transform value using timestamp
                    return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, Long> punctuate(long timestamp) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                }
            })
            .groupByKey(stringSerde, longSerde)
            .count("test_store1").toStream()
            .print();
```

output:

```
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32541
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32542
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32543
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32544
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32545
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32546
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32547
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32548
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32549
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000015]:user_count as of 2018-02-02 12:38 , 32550
```

Comment: Did you try `KTable#mapValues()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timestamp using `KStream#transform()`:

```
table
  .toStream()
  .transform(() -> new Transformer<Object, Object, KeyValue<Object,Object>>() {
      private ProcessorContext context;

      @Override
      public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
          this.context = context;
      }

      @Override
      public KeyValue<Object, Object> transform(Object key, Object value) {
          long timestamp = context.timestamp();
          // transform value using timestamp
          return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
      }

      @Override
      public KeyValue<Object, Object> punctuate(long timestamp) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void close() {
      }
  })
  .to("output");
```

Note this timestamp is the timestamp of the input record that triggered the computation. I assume that's what you're looking for.

Otherwise, if you just need to transform your counts with something like `System.currentTimeMillis()` and you don't need the timestamp from the record, as Matthias points out in his comment you can just use `KTable#mapValue()`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry,that helped to get the timestamp.I edited my post to include code and output,Not sure why it is printing count for the same time even though i am using groupby .Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi Dmittry not yet,I am seeing the count for the same timestamp repeatedly as shown above even though i am grouping .Not sure why?Any thoughts?